# Vim: yank from end of line including last character

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim. Say I'm editing a doc and have added some words to the end of a line. I'm still in edit mode with my cursor at the end of the line.

I then decide that I want to copy the 4 words before my cursor and paste them to the end of the line below.
If I use <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> I miss out the last char.

How would an experienced vim user achieve this?

Comment: I've realised that my question was badly posed. I specified '4' words when what I meant was 'the words I've just typed'. Kay has answered the question as posed but Conner has answered the question I meant.
In view of the question's title I guess I should accept Kay's?

Comment: the "accepted answer" does not necessarily have a formality to it; it's completely up to your judgment. However, that being said, this comment is a little self-serving. Go ahead and accept Kay's answer since he was more expedient and provided a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use this:

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

or:

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

for this specific case where your curosr is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Aadd some words to end<esc>` then just do `j.` to repeat that insertion.